# How to convert decode some special characters in php?

Tags: php, special-characters, decode

I have an encoded string as "%87123". Now when I display that string it should be decoded to "‡123". My code is like below :

```
$code = '%87123';
echo urldecode($code); 
die;
```

I have tried with many different functions like, urldecode, rawurldecode, htmlentities, iconv and many others.
If someone can help for this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure why you expect that string to get decoded to your expectation... Trying `urlencode('‡123')` I get `%E2%80%A1123`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like that is a url encoded version of a string not in the standard `UTF-8` encoding (as commonly used today, especially in the web environment), but in the old fashioned, MS-Windows-proprietary `Windows-1252` encoding. That is indeed still used in some MS-Windows version, it is nearly identical with `ISO-8859-1` or `ISO-8859-15`, but as typical for MS tries to be a bit incompatible. You now suffer from the result of that well known strategy...

Take a look at this simple example script:

```
<?php
var_dump(urlencode('‡123'));
var_dump(urldecode('%87123'));
var_dump(iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', urldecode('%87123')));
```

The output is:

```
string(12) "%E2%80%A1123"
string(4) "�123"
string(6) "‡123"
```

So the decoding results in something that *can be* interpreted as a string encoded in `Windows-1252`. If so, and if you then convert it to the standatd `UTF-8` encoding you get the result you expected...

So your situation most likely is that some string encoded in that MS internal encoding got injected into a web environment without getting recoded. Since PHP cannot somehow magically guess that it does its decoding job and delivers the result, which is an invalid UTF-8 encoded string. You have to tell PHP what encoding it should assume, it is impossible to automatically detect that.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works for me. Just one question. How you come to know about this character set?

Comment: Glad to hear I could help ;-) I got quite some experience with data exchange over countless APIs, systems, workflows, ... To be specific: historically grown data collections in the environments of scientific libraries throughout Europe... That includes all sorts of exotic things you suddenly find on your doorstep. You get curious and mistrusting with the time. That habit especially asks for attention the moment MS-Windows systems come into play...